# How can I detect whether the object is 3D?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, 3d

I am trying to build a solution where I could differentiate between a 3D textured surface with the height of around 200 micron and a regular text print.

The following image is a textured surface. The black color here is the base surface.

Regular text print will be the 2D print of the same 3D textured surface.

[image]

[EDIT]

Initial thought about solving this problem, could look like this:

General idea here would be, images shot at different angles of a 3D object would be less related to each other than the images shot for a 2D object in the similar condition.

One of the possible way to verify could be: 1. Take 2 images, with enough light around (flash of the camera). These images should be shot at as far angle from the object plane as possible. Say, one taken at camera making 45 degree at left side and other with the same angle on the right side.

Extract the ROI, perspective correct them.
Find GLCM of the composite of these 2 images. If the contrast of the GLCM is low, then it would be a 3D image, else a 2D.
Please pardon the language, open for edit suggestion.

Comment: are you able to influence the lighting conditions? e.g. can you use a spot with a sharp angle? Is the structure coming out of the surface or is it going inside the surface?

Comment: Could you show an image of "regular text print" for comparison?

Comment: @Micka I'm using a mobile camera to detect the 3D. I can not govern if there will be a spot with a sharp angle. The pale white colored structure is coming out of the surface.

Comment: @chtz the regular text print is any printed paper, any normal printer that you know or a 2D projection or if you print the attached image using any colored printer.

Comment: imho this won't work. 0.2 millimeter difference with mobile camera and without adjusting environment or nice assumptions, but I might be wrong. Good luck.

Comment: @Micka what would you propose the best way to achieve after certain assumptions?

Comment: make photo from the same position (not possible on hand held)  while having light source on different places between the frames ... Then you can try to detect the shading on the slopes it should be dependend on the light direction and 3D shape.. But the height difference is so small so I fear normal light will not do anything and may be A LASER or something would be better. Theoretically  you should be able to detect 2D/3D from single image detecting the lighting of surface pattern (2D should be more smooth (no bumps etc)) but without seeing both 2D and 3D images is hard to say...

Comment: after some considerations, I can make more than one photos and that too from different angles available, if that solves the problem.

Comment: @arvid.mohan if you can take two images of the same scene from two different angles you can calculate the disparity map like [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html). This could solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried viewing your Q with my 3D glasses. It still looks 2D to me. In all seriousness, though, it's not clear to me what you are asking. Can you post images that we can compare visually. for example this "textured" image and a "printed" version of it so we can see what you mean? I'm guessing they would be indistinguishable just as I had no way of knowing that image was a *texture* if you hadn't told me so. Basic rule of thumb: If you can't explain it in English, you have no way of saying it in computer code.

Answer (score 0):

General idea here would be, images shot at different angles of a 3D object would be less related to each other than the images shot for a 2D object in the similar condition.

One of the possible way to verify could be:
1. Take 2 images, with enough light around (flash of the camera). These images should be shot at as far angle from the object plane as possible. Say, one taken at camera making 45 degree at left side and other with the same angle on the right side.

2. Extract the ROI, perspective correct them.
3. Find GLCM of composite of these 2 images. If contrast of the GLCM is low, then it would be a 3D image, else a 2D.

Please pardon the language, open for edit suggestion.

Comment: this is not an answer to your question. If you have more information to clarify your question, please edit and improve your question. do not put it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get another image which 
 different angle or
 sharper angle or
 different lighting condition
you may get result. However, using two image with different angle with calibrate camera can get stereo vision image which solve your problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty complex problem and there is no plug-in-and-go solution for this. Using light (structured or laser) or shadow to detect a height of 0.2 mm will almost surely not work with an acceptable degree of confidence, no matter of how much "photos" you take. (This is just my personal intuition, in computer vision we verify if something works by actually testing).

GLCM is a nice feature to describe texture, but it is, as far as I know, used to verify if there is a pattern in the texture, so, I believe it would output a positive value for 2D print text if there is some kind of repeating pattern.

I would let the computer learn what is text, what is texture. Just extract a large amount of 3D and 2D data, and use a machine learning engine to learn which is what. If the feature space is rich enough, it may be able to find a way to differentiate one from another, in a way our human mind wouldn't be able to. The feature space should consist of edge and colour features.

If the system environment is stable and controlled, this approach will work specially well, since the training data will be so similar to the testing data.

For this problem, I'd start by computing colour and edge features (local image pixel sums over different edge and colour channels) and try a boosted classifier. Boosted classifiers aren't the state of the art when it comes to machine learning, but they are good at not overfitting (meaning you can just insert as much data as you want), and will most likely work in a stable environment.

Hope this helps,

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I doubt that you haven't taken into consideration that 2D print is nothing but printed photo of the 3D image. Have you?

Comment: So, you'll have a camera that will be looking at actual textured surface or printed images of the same textured surface, and you need to tell them appart? Is that it?

Comment: Pedro, yes, exactly.

Comment: You can fool a edge based face-recognition system by showing a printed photo of a person's face to the camera.

Still, the best way to figure out if this task is achievable is by trying machine learning. If there are features that will work to differentiate them, a machine learning engine will find them.

Comment: I was thinking on the lines of clicking more than one picture of the image at different angles. Multiple pictures of a 3D image will be a lot different at contour edges from each other, while pictures of a 2D image will be similar (after performing perspective correction). And GLCM will pitch in some additional weight. WDYT?

Comment: I'd have to know how your setup is, and how you images are. I really can't graps your problem without example images.

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out why this "Multiple pictures of a 3D image will be a lot different at contour edges from each other, while pictures of a 2D image will be similar" would be the case, If the depth of the texture really is 0.2mm high, then in my mind images would look almost identical.

Comment: I was trying with 3D images with 0.5mm height, I was able to differentiate. 0.2mm becomes tricky and so the question stands here. Haha

Comment: Also, this is a raised texture, don't know how to figure it out.
One more thing can be tried out, instead of checking (whitelisting) features of a 3D image, we can negate all the cases using which a 2D image is printed. Can we blacklist the printing signatures of a list of printers?